# Laravel force users to change password on first login attempt

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.6 (5.7) force change password on first login attempt

In my project, I uploaded users in bulk by importing from excel with a default /general password for all users

The problem is, I have to write a script to force all users to change the password when they log-in for the first time.

Comment: Welcome. It's unclear what you asking. Can you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: there is a logic in Laravel 5.7 in which each of the users that register must verify their respective email use field table and middleware route, for example, user->email_verified_at 
    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); 
can this logic be adopted in first login attempte must change password?

Answer (score 13):

The solution is that I have to add "password_changed_at" column to the users' table and in my home controller index I added this code below (since every new user is directed to home)

```
 public function index()
    {   
        if ((Auth::user()->password_change_at == null)) {
           return redirect(route('change-password'));
        }
        else{
           
            return view('home');    
        }
        
    }
```

I did make use of change password of [setting-up-change-password-with-laravel](https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/)
but I added an update to the code which is below

```
 //Change Password
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('new-password'));
        $user->password_change_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); //add new line of code
        $user->save();
```